Knit R Studio no muestra nada en html
a alguien le ha ocurrido esto? Que el código en R Studio Markdown no muestra error pero al momento de ver el html de knit sale en blanco? me falta algo?, les adjunto el código completo:
title: "Verificación de Nombres de Columnas"
author: "Nombre"
date: "2024-06-01"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = TRUE, warning = TRUE, error = TRUE)
# Configurar el mirror de CRAN
r <- getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
options(repos = r)

# Instalar las bibliotecas necesarias si no están instaladas
if (!require(readxl)) install.packages('readxl', dependencies=TRUE)
if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages('dplyr', dependencies=TRUE)

# Cargar las bibliotecas necesarias
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
# Seleccionar archivos
cat("Por favor, selecciona el archivo de datos de propiedad\n")
file_airbnb <- file.choose()

cat("Por favor, selecciona el archivo de datos de fechas\n")
file_environment <- file.choose()

# Leer los datos de propiedad de Airbnb
data_airbnb <- read_excel(file_airbnb)

# Leer los datos de fechas de Environment
data_environment <- read_excel(file_environment)

# Mostrar los nombres de las columnas de ambos datasets
cat("Nombres de las columnas en data_airbnb:\n")
print(names(data_airbnb))

cat("Nombres de las columnas en data_environment:\n")
print(names(data_environment))

# Mostrar las primeras filas de los datos para inspección
cat("Primeras filas de los datos de Airbnb:\n")
print(head(data_airbnb))

cat("Primeras filas de los datos de Environment:\n")
print(head(data_environment))

Lo que hace esto es al ejecutarse, pedir que se seleccione el archivo 1 y luego el archivo 2, se procesa al 100% pero no muestra nada relevante al momento de llegar al 100%, solamente muestra el título de la página y el autor.
Llevo horas revisando y no encuentro el motivo, alguien lo sabe?
Gracias de antemano!

Probaste con el ejemplo de R Markdown que viene defecto al crear un documento .Rmd? Quizás es tu software, porque el código parece estar bien

Hombre si, con la plantilla que trae cuando se crea el archivo desde el principio si funciona, y renderiza lo que trae, por eso es que no entiendo que es lo que pasa

Prueba separando el chunk de setup de las funciones que usas para imprimir valores en pantalla. Quizás eso está haciendo q tu código falle
